# limit of the sequence $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}a_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}a_k$, with $a_k$ for every $k\geq1$, with $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k=0$. Suppose that the sequence $s_{2n+1}$, $n\geq0$, is decreasing and the sequence $s_{2n}$, $n\geq1$, is increasing. Prove that $s_n$ converges.

Before this exercise, I have proved the following result

> If $x_n$ is increasing, $y_n$ is decreasing with $\lim (y_n-x_n)=0$ and, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $y_n-x_n\geq0$, then both the sequences converge for the same limit.

I was thinking that I can use this one, because $x_n=s_{2n}$ is increasing and $y_n=s_{2n+1}$ is decreasing and $x_n-y_n\geq0$ and

$$\lim(y_n-x_n)=\lim(s_1+s_3+\cdots)+\lim(s_2+s_4+\cdots)=\lim s_n$$

then $s_n$ converges.... Do you agree with me?

Comment: Why is $x_n$ increasing?

Comment: you're right, we dont know anything about the $a_n$ terms

Comment: @MarcosPaulo In "$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}a_n$", should the final "$a_n$" be "$a_k$" instead? Otherwise, as it is now, you have $s_n = a_n$ if $n$ is odd and $s_n = 0$ is $n$ is even.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes... $a_k$. I have just corrected.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Thanks for confirming and making the correction. I have thus updated my answer to remove the initial part about assuming it's supposed to be $a_k$ and the issues I had if it was actually meant to be $a_n$ instead.

Comment: Should "with $a_k$ for every $k\ge1$" be "with $a_k\ge0$ for every $k\ge1$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the series

$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}a_k \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note by "decreasing" I assume it means $\le$ and by "increasing" I assume it means $\ge$. If it's to be considered "strict" instead, then replace the $\le$ with $\lt$, and $\ge$ with $\gt$ below.

You have

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k=0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since the sequence $s_{2n + 1}$, $n \geq 0$, is decreasing, you thus have that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
s_{2n+3} - s_{2n+1} & \le 0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+3} (-1)^{k+1}a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k+1}a_k & \le 0 \\
(-1)^{(2n+3) + 1}a_{2n+3} + (-1)^{(2n+2) + 1}a_{2n+2} & \le 0 \\
a_{2n+3} - a_{2n+2} & \le 0 \\
a_{2n+2} & \ge a_{2n+3}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Similarly, since the sequence $s_{2n}$, $n\geq1$, is increasing. you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
s_{2n+2} - s_{2n} & \ge 0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2} (-1)^{k+1}a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k+1}a_k & \ge 0 \\
(-1)^{(2n+2) + 1}a_{2n+2} + (-1)^{(2n+1) + 1}a_{2n+1} & \ge 0 \\
-a_{2n+2} + a_{2n+1} & \ge 0 \\
a_{2n+1} & \ge a_{2n+2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using $n = 0$ in \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$a_2 \ge a_3 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

while using $n = 1$ in \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$a_3 \ge a_4 \implies a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Now, repeating the procedure using $n = 1$ in \eqref{eq3A} and $n = 2$ in \eqref{eq4A}, and combining the results with \eqref{eq6A}, gives

$$a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4 \ge a_5 \ge a_6 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

You can fairly easily prove, such as by using induction (which I'm leaving to you to do), that

$$a_k \ge a_{k + 1}, \; \forall \; k \ge 2 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

This means the $a_k$ terms, apart from possibly $a_1$, are all monotonically decreasing. Thus, using \eqref{eq2A}, the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) states that $s_n$ converges.

---

Note in your proof attempt, if you let $x_n = s_{2n}$ and $y_n = s_{2n+1}$, then $x_n - y_n = -(-1)^{(2n + 1) + 1}a_{2n + 1} = -a_{2n + 1}$, which is actually $\le 0$ instead as you have $x_n$ and $y_n$ mixed around. Also, in your next line where you state

$$\lim(y_n - x_n) = \lim(s_1 + s_3 + \cdots) + \lim(s_2 + s_4 + \cdots) = \lim s_n$$

you seem to use that $y_n$ and $x_n$ are the sums of $s_{2n + 1}$ and $s_{2n}$ from $1$ up to $n$ rather than just being those terms as you earlier defined them.

Nonetheless, with your definitions, you have $y_n - x_n = a_{2n + 1}$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}(y_n - x_n) = 0$. Also, as shown in \eqref{eq8A}, all $a_{k}$ for $k \ge 2$ are non-negative (as it's a monotonically decreasing series with a limit of $0$) so for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $y_n - x_n \ge 0$. Thus, you could also use the result which you stated you proved earlier.

Comment: Based on your definition of increasing sequence, $a_n=0$ is increasing, because of $0 \geqslant 0$ (and it's decreasing as well). (+1)

Comment: Do you think it is really need to use that result for this exercise, considering that in the book this exercise comes before the section about series?

Comment: @MarcosPaulo I'm not quite sure what "that result" is referring to. If you're asking about the result you tried to use, then it's not necessary because the alternating series test is sufficient, as my answer shows. Note there's several different ways to prove the result, with some of them potentially being interdependent (e.g., your previous result may have used, in one way or another, the alternating series test proof). Since I'm not familiar with what exactly you've already learned in the book & what has yet to come, I don't think I can offer much more help than this.

Comment: At this point of the book I only know about the convergence/divergence of monotonic sequences

Comment: @MarcosPaulo As shown in the answer, the series is montonically decreasing. I'm not sure what you've studied about the convergence/divergence of such sequences, but if the limit of the terms is $0$, as it is here, then the alternating series test shows the sum of the alternating terms converges. Have you studied this test and, if not, are there other tests or methods you have studied which can be applied to this problem?

Comment: I have been actually reviewg this contents after almost 10 years. I wiil reach the topics about series in a couple of days. I know there are many techniques to verify the convergence of a serie, but since the exercise the I posted here is in the topic of sequence, I did not want to resolve it with those techniques.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Thanks for providing more details. You need to use some technique to prove convergence, but as I'm not sure what you specifically consider to be allowed or not allowed, I don't know what to suggest.